# Stripe API: Obtaining Subscription Name

Tags: c#, stripe-payments, blazor-server-side

I'm hoping that someone would be able to offer some assistance utilizing the Stripe API. I'm using the Stripe API for dotNet. I'm trying to get the subscription name, not just the subscription id. However, I'm not able to figure out how to do this. Note, that I can get back response data from Stripe, so I've inspected the results and could not locate the subscription name.

Comment: Hi, can you clarify what you mean by ‘Name’ of the subscription? According to the Subscriptions API, https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/object there is not a name property. Instead, there is a description property, https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/object#subscription_object-description   which is displayed to the customer. To obtain the Subscription description, you can call the Retrieve Subscriptions request, https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/retrieve and look at description.

Comment: It may be the description that I need to use. But thank you for your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To obtain the description of the Subscription, you can call the Retrieve Subscriptions [request](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/retrieve) and look at description.